# Woocommerce Checkout page edit

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-theming, checkout

Does someone knows how to change the seleceted part in the image below in woocommerce?
[image]

I have edited the entire woocommerce checkout page, but i cant find where to edit this part?

Comment: This looks like a work of some newsletter plugin. Maybe Mailchimp etc.

Comment: @Bhanu thanks,i've been banging my head against the wall with this :D it was in creative mail. It never crossed my mind that it could be that :D

Comment: You can fix it without actually deactivating the plugin. You would need to use remove_action and jsut remove the action which is basically adding this line.